# Combine field value of two different columns in one single column

Tags: oracle10g

I have a table name "Numbers".I have two columns viz. Col_1 & Col_2

[image]

Now, I want to write a query so that I can display values of the above two columns in a single column Col_3 as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use UNION

```
SELECT Col_1 AS Col_3 
FROM Numbers

UNION

SELECT Col_2 AS Col_3 
FROM Numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the unique values in both tables and don't mind scanning the table twice, then:

```
select col1 as col3
from   numbers
union
select col2
from   numbers
```

If you want to preserve all values then use a UNION ALL:

```
select col1 as col3
from   numbers
union all
select col2
from   numbers
```

If the table is large enough that avoiding two scans would be preferable:

```
with cte_two_rows as (
  select 1 col from dual union all
  select 2 col from dual)
select
  case col
    when 1 then col1
    when 2 then col2
  end col3
from
  numbers cross join cte_two_rows
```